# How to connect an external android device to android studio - Note, the device is not a phone/tablet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-9.0-pie

I am new to android development. I am working on building an android application and test it on a real device. Testing with mobile was straightforward and I was able to do it by enabling developer mode on my android phone. But now, I want to test it on **non-mobile**. Example: external android camera.

How can I do that? Because I don't see developer options on this device (I connected the device to a display window, and searched the setting options) Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You would have to ask the device manufacturer. Or, at the very least, tell us the make and model of the device.